# JQuery UI dragable (can't correctly stop it)

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, draggable

i have some problems with dragable UI.
In some conditions i need to stop dragging. It is very dynamic. I try to give it more simple.

What i do:

```
drag : (function(e,ui){
           if (ui.position.left > 400){// in my example 400 is variable whitch calculates every drag event
                        return false;
      }            
}
```

But if i do this. When i returning false. All drag is stoping. And if i want to drag in another direction, i must do 'mouseup' and 'mousedown' again.

How can i create such behavior without stopping drag?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't any method that cancels only one "dragging", but you can set the position of the object using ui.position

```
return false
```

raises an error and it doesn't work effectively. The following piece of code worked for me well.

```
$('#draggablediv').draggable({
        drag: function (event, ui) {
            if (your_condition) { // for example: ui.position.left < 100
                ui.position.left = ui.position.left_old
                ui.position.top = ui.position.top_old
            }
            ui.position.left_old = ui.position.left
            ui.position.top_old = ui.position.top
        }
    })
```